# Grails 3 run-script - Script execution error: No transactionManager

Tags: grails, groovy, datasource, transactional

I'm trying to use the run-script command with one of my services in Grails 3.

I have all my services marked with the @Transactional tag. I made a "standalone" groovy file in the folder src/main/groovy that declares one of the services and wants to call a method on it.

My stand-alone groovy file declares a dataSource and sets it like this:

```
def dataSource = new OracleDataSource(URL: 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:local', user: 'test', password: '');
```

I can verify it works within the stand-alone groovy file by doing this:

```
        sql = new Sql(dataSource);

    sql.eachRow("SELECT COUNT(*) AS MYCOUNT FROM MYTABLE") {
        myCount = it."MYCOUNT";
    }
```

and it works fine.

I then pass the dataSource to my service class as a param. Note that when I run my Grails app as a "normal" Grails app, I don't need to do this, as the service "already knows" how to initialize the dataSource property that it has. But when running my stand-alone groovy file with "grails run-script" and wanting to use the service, I do this:

```
applicationFunctionService.setSession(dataSource);
```

But then afterwards when I call a method on my service that involves doing an SQL/database-interaction, it throws this error (when using grails run-script)

```
Script execution error: No transactionManager was specified. Using @Transactional or @Rollback requires a valid configured transaction manager. If you are running in a unit test ensure the test has been properly configured and that you run the test suite not an individual test method.
:runScript FAILED
```

Note that my intention is not to do a test per say... I actually want to have a "stand-alone" groovy file that invokes my Grails service within the Grails-context. I'd also like to leave the service as-is with the @Transactional tag. Though I wouldn't mind "turning @Transaction off" within the context of my stand-alone groovy class, if that's possible.

Is there a way to deal with this error?

Comment: The other thing worth mentioning... In my service class, if I use: org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional instead of: grails.transaction.Transactional then I do not get the problem with run-script. The problem only happens with  grails.transaction.Transactional. I don't know the difference between them, and would prefer to stick with  grails.transaction.Transactional since that seems to be the "default" and what my app has always worked with so far.